Substitution within derivative
I have a problem with a (hopefully) simple substitution. Lets say i have a function $y(x)$. And now for some reason (the reason being I am being told to do so) I want to substitute $s=x-1$ and $u=y+1$. And now I want to write down the expression for the derivative of the function which should supposably somehow result in the following.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \ldots=\frac{du}{ds}$$
Here are my thoughts so far:
$$y=u-1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}.$$
But I have no clue how to get to
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{ds}$$

Chain rule : $du/ds=(du/dy)(dy/dx)(dx/ds)$?

$du/dx=(du/ds)(ds/dx)=(du/ds)1$.

@AnneBauval but this implies that u is a function of s(x), right? While s(x) is obvious, I don't get the u(s).

$y$ is a function of $x$ and $u=1+y$ is a function of $s=x-1$. $$u(s)=1+y(s+1).$$
